# Why do my buttons wont show up?

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to build a bingo got the following source code, which should create a JFrame with 25 buttons placed in a 5x5 matrix. But none of my button gets drawn on the window in any kind.

I ve created a Jpanel on which the buttons are placed, the locations and such are not specific, finetuning will come later, first thing is to even get them drawn on the window.

Bingo Buttons is a class which extends JFrame and simply adds two methods, one to toggle its status from true to false and the other way around and also an method (isSet) to check if the buttons is currently true or false.

bingoField is an String Array which holds nothing but the data which the buttons should get.

I dont get why it does nothing, please help me out. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

```
public class BingoFrame extends JFrame {

public static final int BINGOSIZE=25;
public static final int BUTTON_X=50;
public static final int BUTTON_Y=50;

public BingoFrame() {
    setResizable(false);
    String[] bingoField = null;
    BingoButton[] buttons=new BingoButton[25];

try {
  bingoField = Utils.getRandomBingoField("Test");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

this.setTitle("BS Bingo");
this.setResizable(false);
this.setLocation(50, 50);
this.setSize(600, 800);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 594, 772);
getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

for(int i=0;i<BINGOSIZE;i++) {
  buttons[i] = new BingoButton("Text");
}

//decorate buttons and add an action listener
for(int i=0;i<BINGOSIZE;i++) {
  final BingoButton temp = buttons[i];
  temp.setText(bingoField[i]);
  temp.setBackground(Color.white);
  temp.setForeground(Color.blue);
  temp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BUTTON_X,BUTTON_Y));

  temp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    boolean toggle = false;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (!temp.isSet()) {
        temp.setBackground(Color.blue);
        temp.setForeground(Color.white);
      } else {
        temp.setBackground(Color.white);
        temp.setForeground(Color.blue);
      }
      temp.toggle();
    }
  });

  buttons[i]=temp;
} 

//set Location for the buttons
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    buttons[i].setLocation(100,(50*i)+10*(i+1));
}    
for(int i=5;i<10;i++) {
    buttons[i].setLocation(160,(50*i)+10*(i+1));
}
for(int i=10;i<15;i++) {
    buttons[i].setLocation(220,(50*i)+10*(i+1));
}
for(int i=15;i<20;i++) {
    buttons[i].setLocation(280,(50*i)+10*(i+1));
}
for(int i=20;i<25;i++) {
    buttons[i].setLocation(340,(50*i)+10*(i+1));
}

//add buttons to the panel
for(int i=0;i<BINGOSIZE;i++) {
  buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
}    

this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please change the title of your window to make it less profane

Comment: Is this the complete code? You are missing the class and main method...

Comment: Its actually just what is useful for the frame.  The main method (in another class) simply is the creation of the object. I ve added the rest of the code for the frameclass.

Comment: So your frame shows up but your buttons don't?

Comment: Exactly. I ve done it with a flowlayout before with that i works like it should if i wanted to do it with the flow layout, but i want to do it as an absolute layout, but as soon as i write .setLayout(null) only the window shows up and none of the buttons.

Comment: Oracle says to use a layout if possible. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Actually i dont, i will do it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? For eclipse, intelliJ and netbeans, they all have built-in debuggers.

Comment: I do use eclipse and i debugged it but i didnt found something that might help me to go further.

Comment: Try invoking repaint on each of the Buttons.

Comment: Set a breakpoint just before the place where it doesn't show the buttons, and click step over for each line of code in Eclipse. Also check out this [Beginner's guide to debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer.

I ve changed the Layout of the Panel to Grid Layout. This alligns the buttons just where they should be in a 5x5 matrix and also with the wanted gap between. This makes also the code for the positioning completly obsolete.

By simply changing the Layout to GridLayout all of my Problems were gone.

Comment: (1-) if you want a grid, then use a `GridLayout`, not a FlowLayout. Also get rid of the null layout for the frame. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. There is no reason to use a null layout for something like this.

Comment: You re right, i simply didnt thought about that. My 1st thought was, if the panel is just as big as it needs to be the buttons while be where they should be because of the linebreak. It worked on the 1st try so i didnt leave a 2nd thought on it. But you re right, the GridLayout makes much more sense. I will edit the anwser.